# How do I add a directory to MANPATH or INFOPATH?

Tags: manpage, info

I think I understand the instructions given in [How to add a directory to the PATH?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path) about adding directories to $PATH. But I don't understand how to add directories to $MANPATH or $INFOPATH.

Also -- in googling around for help I have noticed that sometimes directions say `export PATH=/usr/share/lib/something:$PATH` and sometimes they say `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/share/lib/something`. Which is it?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

1. These 2 are almost the same:

   ```
   export PATH=/usr/share/lib/something:$PATH 
   export PATH=$PATH:/usr/share/lib/something
   ```

   The only difference is that the first one puts the directory to add in front and the second one puts it behind the current directories in `$PATH`. It only matters if there are commands inside `/usr/share/lib/something` that have the same name inside one of the directories in `$PATH`.
2. To add directories to `$MANPATH` or `$INFOPATH` as required from the link you posted you do that by changing the config files inside the link.

   It says to open the global version of `bash.bashrc` with:

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/bash.bashrc
   ```

   and to add at the end:

   ```
   PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2010/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH; export PATH
   MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf/doc/man:$MANPATH; export MANPATH
   INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf/doc/info:$INFOPATH; export INFOPATH
   ```

   This sets `$PATH`, `$MANPATH` and `$INFOPATH`. And it also tells you to edit `/etc/manpath.config` with:

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/manpath.config
   ```

   and to add

   ```
   MANPATH_MAP /usr/local/texlive/2010/bin/x86_64-linux /usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf/doc/man
   ```

   underneath `# set up PATH to MANPATH mapping`.

---

If you are unsure about this make a backup 1st (never a bad thing) with:

```
sudo cp /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/bash.backup_$(date +"%Y_%m_%d").bashrc
sudo cp /etc/manpath.config /etc/manpath.backup_$(date +"%Y_%m_%d").config
```

The weird string changes into the current date. If you mess up just copy the backup back over the original file:

```
$ touch test1
$ cp test1 test1.$(date +"%Y_%m_%d")
$ ls
test1  test1.2014_11_14
```

Comment: I installed texlive 2012 on Ubuntu Precise and `echo $MANPATH` returns `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/doc/man` to me. When I add the paths to the configuration bash reports `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/doc/man:/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/doc/man` and zsh still report `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/doc/man`. For zsh I add the paths to `/etc/zsh/zshrc`. I am not sure if this is correct. I also tried editing `/etc/environment`, as suggested [here](http://www.tuxtrix.com/2010/04/fix-manual-entry-found-for-in-3-easy.html), though without success.

Comment: @JJD - see also this post: [Custom help / man -like command (for reminders) - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/119186/8069)

Comment: What command can I see after writting `MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf/doc/man:$MANPATH; export MANPATH`? I tried `man tlmgr`and it says that it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 7):

If your man pages are in `/usr/local/myproject/man`, all you need to do is add that to (the end of) `/etc/manpath.config`:

```
MANDATORY_MANPATH        /usr/local/myproject/man
```

Comment: The *potential* problem with this answer is that it gives you **no control** over the **order** of the folders you add.

Answer (score 1):

> `x:y:z:$PATH` or `$PATH:x:y:z`?

Barely different. `$PATH` contains a `:`-separated list of places where bash (the shell/terminal) should check for a program.

For example if you type `cat` the way the terminal understands what that means is to look through the first, second, third elements of `$PATH`, then [save](https://superuser.com/a/881793/65499) the first location it finds for later invocations of `cat`.

If I have two different versions of a program in two different places, with one of them being preferred, and `$PATH` tells the shell to search in the wrong order, then there's a problem. Otherwise, no problem.

---

> export

Open a terminal and type

```
echo $a
a=5
echo a
echo $a
```

You'll see that `a=5` set the variable value and `$a` refers to the variable name, not the value.

Open a second terminal and type `echo $a`. It should again be blank.

The difference between `export` and assignment (`=`) is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158091/defining-a-variable-with-or-without-export.

Answer (score 0):

If you've bothered to check, by default the environment variable `MANPATH` ***does not exist*** in current versions of Ubuntu. Try this:

```bash
echo $PATH

echo $MANPATH
```

This is due to `man`'s dependence on the command `manpath`. Run it from the command line, and you'll find that its output is (effectively) MANPATH, yet we already know that no variable MANPATH is defined (by default):

```bash
manpath
/usr/local/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man
```

The directories where manuals reside is contained in `/etc/manpath.config`, and you can edit that file to add new folders. Try this; edit `/etc/manpath.config`, and then see the result by running `manpath`. If that's all you need (to add some folders containing manuals), this may be a good solution for you.

In my case, I needed to also set the ***order*** in which these manual folders were searched. I found no way to set order by editing `/etc/manpath.config` (please correct me if I missed that). But of course you can do that when you edit your PATH env var, and you can do the same with MANPATH as it turns out. Here are some possibilities:

1. To specify MANPATH independent of `manpath`:

```bash
export MANPATH="/first/path/tomanuals:/second/path/tomanuals:etc/etc/etc"
```

You **may** get a warning from your system to the following effect:

```
manpath: warning: $MANPATH set, ignoring /etc/manpath.config
```

Which is exactly what we wanted.

2. To augment `manpath` such that the folder being added is searched **first**:

```bash
export MANPATH="/some/dir/with/manuals/man:$(manpath)"
```

Of course you can change the order around to suit your needs.

3. Finally if you screw up, or just want to return control to `manpath`, do this:

```bash
unset MANPATH
```