# apt-get errors after TeX Live 2012 update with tlmgr

Tags: 12.04, apt, dpkg, latex

I am running TeX Live 2012 on Ubuntu Precise. For the installation I followed [this tutorial](http://weblog.avp-ptr.de/20120710/how-to-manually-install-tex-live-2012/). Yesterday, I updated the packages (about 40 items) for Tex Live 2012 using the following tool.

```
$ sudo tlmgr --gui
```

The updates have been installed successfully and everything still worked.

Today, I noticed that `apt-get` outputs errors when I run `sudo apt-get install something` or `sudo apt-get autoremove`. Here is the console output of the latter command.

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.

After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up texlive-base (2009-15) ...
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXMFMAIN... 
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXLIVE... 
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Done.

texconfig: unknown option `paperconf' given as argument for `texconfig dvips'
texconfig: try `texconfig dvips' for help
texconfig: unknown option `paperconf' given as argument for `texconfig dvipdfmx'
texconfig: try `texconfig dvipdfmx' for help
texconfig: unknown option `paperconf' given as argument for `texconfig xdvi'
texconfig: try `texconfig xdvi' for help
texconfig: unknown option `paperconf' given as argument for `texconfig pdftex'
texconfig: try `texconfig pdftex' for help
texconfig: unknown option `paperconf' given as argument for `texconfig dvips'
texconfig: try `texconfig dvips' for help

dpkg: error processing texlive-base (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-latex-base:
 texlive-latex-base depends on texlive-base (>= 2009-1); however:
  Package texlive-base is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing texlive-latex-base (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-bibtex-extra:
 texlive-bibtex-extra depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2009-1); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing texlive-bibtex-extra (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup 
error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup 
error from a previous failure.

Errors were encountered while processing:
 texlive-base
 texlive-latex-base
 texlive-bibtex-extra
```

LaTeX itself still works fine as far as I can see.

**Note:** Just in case the following has something to do with the main problem. I also noticed a while ago that the man path does no longer point to the usual folders. The [MANPATH problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60765/how-do-i-add-a-directory-to-manpath-or-infopath) has been described before. However, I could not solve it on my machine.

```
$ echo $MANPATH
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/doc/man
```

Comment: The errors indicate dependency issues with the official (2009) TeX Live and whatever you installed. I'd recommend removing it and following this [Q/A](http://askubuntu.com/q/163682/58612) to install "official" TeX Live 2012 on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: I will try in three weeks, however, I cannot jeopardize my production system right now.

Comment: @izx: Please convert that comment to an answer.

Comment: @MartinSchröder ... although izx's answer is an alternative solution, it does not particularly answer the question.

Comment: @izx What do you suggest I need to uninstall/delete before running the PPA in order to have a clean system afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I uninstalled all TexLive-related packages which let the error messages disappear.
Here is what I did ...

```
sudo apt-get remove tex-common texlive-base texlive-binaries texlive-common \
  texlive-doc-base texlive-latex-base texlive-local texlive-latex-base-doc
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

I will probably use the advertised [texlive-backports PPA](https://askubuntu.com/a/163683/18533) to reinstall TexLive.

I also found out that the MANPATH problem originated from a custom configuration I made somewhen. This was indirectly loaded from my `.zshrc` file.

```
# TexLive 2012
export MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/doc/man
```