# How can I install petrify and set it up?

Tags: software-installation, environment-variables, paths

I want to install [petrify](http://www.lsi.upc.edu/~jordicf/petrify/distrib/home.html) -- a tool for simulation of Asynchronous Circuits -- so I downloaded the file and in this folder there is an INSTALL file that says:

```
 You should define properly define the variables PATH and MANPATH
 of your environment including the "bin" and "man" directories
 of petrify respectively.
```

What should I do?

Comment: This seems to be a problem with a particular program. Please contact its developers or at least provide a link to it and the instructions you are following.

Comment: See [How to add a directory to the PATH?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-the-path) and [How do I add a directory to MANPATH or INFOPATH?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60765/how-do-i-add-a-directory-to-manpath-or-infopath) - it will be difficult to be more specific without more information about the tool you installed

Comment: this is the link of Software 
(http://www.lsi.upc.edu/~jordicf/petrify/distrib/home.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Petrify website](http://www.lsi.upc.edu/%7Ejordicf/petrify/distrib/home.html), I downloaded the ["New version 4.2 (only for Linux)"](http://www.lsi.upc.edu/%7Ejordicf/petrify/distrib/petrify-4.2-linux.tgz) (clicking will download the file).

I unpacked it using `tar`:

```
tar xfz petrify-4.2-linux.tgz
```

Inside the created `petrify` directory is the `INSTALL` file you quoted from, and the directories it refers to, `bin` and `man`. The files are all ready to use and no compiling is required. The two symlinks to the `petrify` binary in `bin` apparently require a program called Dot, but the link to that program on the Petrify website is broken, so I did not attempt to get those two commands working.

Firstly I suggest testing the `petrify` binary. Because it's a 32-bit binary, if you are using a 64-bit system, you will probably get this baffling error:

```
bash: ./petrify: No such file or directory
```

This is explained [in this answer by Gilles](https://askubuntu.com/a/133460/527764).

For me it was sufficient to install `libc6:i386`:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libc6:i386
```

Now the program should run, but it won't do anything without input. If you don't have any files to work on, you can download some [examples](http://www.lsi.upc.edu/%7Ejordicf/petrify/distrib/examples_petrify.tar.gz) (clicking will download) from the site for testing. This file will need to be unpacked with `tar xfz <file>` too. I tested it, but I have no idea how to interpret the output, so I can only tell you that some output files were generated, and there weren't any errors!

To answer your actual question (finally), the reason you might want to set those environment variables is so that you can run `petrify` and `man petrify` from anywhere. Rather than modifying your PATH or setting MANPATH, you could simply copy the files to appropriate locations. Assuming you are in the `petrify` directory where you found the `INSTALL` file, you could run

```
mkdir -p ~/bin
cp bin/petrify ~/bin
```

This directory is automatically prepended to your PATH if it exists by a piece of code in the default `~/.profile` on Ubuntu. You need to `source ~/.profile` to have it adjusted immediately, or log out and log back in for it to take effect (you only have to do that once). Now you can run `petrify` anywhere.

Alternatively, you could copy to `/usr/local/bin`:

```
sudo cp bin/petrify /usr/local/bin
```

This is already in the default PATH. This is the better option if multiple users need access to the program. You can also copy the symlinks from the `bin` directory to the same location as `petrify`.

For the `man`, I copied the file to `/usr/share/man/man1` where the other `man` files on my system live:

```
chmod 644 man/man1/petrify.1
sudo cp man/man1/petrify.1 /usr/share/man/man1
```

Running `man petrify` now brings up a comprehensive `man` page.

If you prefer to configure the PATH and keep the files isolated, you can set the environment variables in your `~/.profile` instead. You can add a line like this to append to the PATH:

```
PATH="$PATH:/path/to/petrify/bin"
```

replacing `/path/to/petrify/bin` with the actual path to the parent directory of the `petrify` binary file, wherever you put it.

Setting MANPATH can also be done in `~/.profile`. Note that the directory structure is

```
man
└── man1
    └── petrify.1
```

If the full path of `petrify.1` were

```
/home/zanna/petrify/man/man1/petrify.1
```

I would set the MANPATH in `~/.profile` like this (without `man1`):

```
export MANPATH=":$HOME/petrify/man"
```

The leading colon [is important here and must not be omitted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197461/how-to-set-manpath-without-overriding-defaults). Also note that you do not need to `export` PATH (it is already exported, and changes to it will be inherited) but you do need to `export` MANPATH.

Comment: and also if anyone wants to use draw_astg , he must be install grapviz in advance so type this in the terminal 
    
`sudo apt-get install graphviz`

Comment: @MiladSabri that's really helpful information. If you want to, you could add an answer yourself about getting the `draw_astg` program working that way. I don't know what it should do, so I don't think I can do a good job of testing it; I think you would manage a lot better than me and it would probably be helpful to others